# What does the datatype specification '9(7)V9T' mean?

Tags: file, types, cobol, numeric, flat

In some functional specs I'm reading they are talking about a numeric format with a 9(7)V9T presentation. 
-How do I interprete this kind of format notations?
-How is this type physically stored in a flatfile (e.g. numeric?, signs? separators?)

Thank you for your wise answers!

Answer (score 2):

A COBOL PICTURE string, such as `9(7)V9T` specifies the general characteristics and editing requirements of an elementary 
data item. A `9` represents a decimal digit, the `(7)` is a repetition factor for the preceding character. In this case
a `9`. The `V` is an implied decimal point. This is all standard COBOL. So far we have an 8 digit decimal number with
an implied decimal point between the 7th and 8th digits.

The `T` is a bit of a curve ball. I have never
actually come across it before.  However, 
I Goolged up [this reference](http://www.felgall.com/cob1.htm).
It states that a `T` in a PICTURE string "... indicates that a display numeric field should only insert the sign into the upper 
half of the last byte if the value is negative". Unfortunately, the author doesn't provide a reference so I can't
give you the source of this convention.

A COBOL picture of `PIC S9(7)V9 USAGE DISPLAY` on an IBM platform conforms to the `9(7)V9T` description you have. This 
data item
takes 8 bytes to represent. Each of the 8 digits are represented in the low 4 bits of each byte with the sign
recorded in the upper 4 bits of the low order byte. This just happens to be the way IBM choose to implement zoned-decimal.
Using a `9(7)V9T` representation makes the representation explicit.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the other answers is that the T is a character to be displayed or printed after the numeric value to represent a specific state, similar to use of CR for credit value or a trailing '-' to indicate a negative value.